# Boost variant built with preprocessor and not variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, variadic-templates, boost-preprocessor

This is the relevant code from the `variant.hpp` file (found here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/boost/variant/variant.hpp)

```
template <
      typename T0_
    , BOOST_VARIANT_ENUM_SHIFTED_PARAMS(typename T)
    >
class variant {
```

Why is this not built with variadic templates?  The answer might be because of backwards compatibility.  If yes, then what exactly is going on in the code above at a high level?  How could the preprocessor be used in such a way that resembles using variadic templates from the user level?

Comment: Have you stumbled upon the flag [BOOST_VARIANT_DO_NOT_USE_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/BOOST_VARIANT_DO_NOT_USE_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES.html)?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at more recent boost versions, then yes it will use variadic templates, if they are available on your compiler.

If you don't have variadic templates, the short answer is, it uses `boost::mpl` instead, and fixes a maximum of 20 or so value types. It uses preprocessor to generate boiler plate for type sequences of size of up to 20.

See here for instance: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/BOOST_VARIANT_LIMIT_TYPES.html

The main drawback is:

- It is harmful to compilation times because it has to expand a ton of macros
- If you have to look in your backtraces / at your mangled type names and they go through `boost::variant` functions, you get spammed with a ton a `boost::detail::variant::void_`, which is the "default argument" / placeholder for the 20 template parameters when you are typically only using a few of them. This really bothered me, but more experience people told me to get over it. :) I think it is universally agreed that variadic templates result in better error messages and stack traces though.

Comment: Which version of boost are you referring to?  I just downloaded 1_61_0 from their website and it still has the same code :( (in `boost/variant/variant.hpp`)

Comment: @Curious what compiler/version are you using? What `std=c++XYZ` flag are you setting?

Comment: @TinyT Oh no I just downloaded the code and went into the folder I mentioned and looked at the code and did not find variadic templates... Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: @Curious Looks like the magic is happening outside in [http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/variant/variant_fwd.hpp](variant_fwd.hpp). The macros there are changing the meaning of `BOOST_VARIANT_ENUM_PARAMS` depending on compiler capabilities. For example: have you specified `-std=c++11` when building Boost?

Comment: Nobody gets over boost stack traces